# What are appropriate ways to use matching with clustered data (with hierarchical structure)?

Tags: multilevel-analysis, causality, matching, cluster-sample

In my setting, I have post-intervention observational data in which individuals are nested into villages. The treatment consists of an information campaign that targeted villages in a non-random manner. The campaign attempted to change the attitudes of individuals. I have village-level information with 230 units, roughly split half in treatment and half in control. I also have individual-level data. At least there are 25 individuals sampled in each of the villages, in total ~5700. The individuals interviewed are aged 18-39 and were randomly sampled. I have pre-intervention data (through recall) for some of the key variables that, in principle, determined village selection. The concrete question is, **what are appropriate ways to use matching in this setting?**

[Rosenbaum (2020)](https://dlab.epfl.ch/teaching/spring2022/cs727/papers/rosenbaum2020modern.pdf) and [King, et al (2019)](https://gking.harvard.edu/publications/why-propensity-scores-should-not-be-used-formatching) say that Optimal Multilevel Matching implemented in the [matchMulti package from R](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/matchMulti/matchMulti.pdf) seems to be the correct approach. An important advantage is that it has a clustering correction at the level of the intervention and paired clusters. Also, it seems the correct way to address matching in the context of clustered data.

**Are there any matching approaches or methods that I might be overlooking, or no need to look further?**

Comment: The question may in fact be: why would you match them at all? Since the data are already collected, the only reason to match would be to reduce the data, which, with modern computers, isn't necessary at all. You should be more concerned on how to implement a proper survey design to assess the impact of this cluster-level effect.

Comment: My objective is to assess any potential effect of the information campaign on individual-level attitudes. The conditions constrained the research design. Since treatment has already occurred and is nonrandom, I am using matching to construct statistically similar control and intervention groups. I didn't have the luxury of pre-intervention data to identify a counterfactual. I checked and there are large differences between the treated and the control groups in the characteristics associated with the treatment status. Matching can help to obtain statistically similar treated and control groups

Comment: One other bit of info: you say the campaign was "non-random", can you clarify? Is this a stepped wedge design? Furthermore, you cannot claim to have "pre-intervention" data from recall - that is post-intervention data.

Comment: Re nonrandom, government officials selected treated villages based on their contextual knowledge. The criteria they used are villages where individuals have more propensity to migrate. The campaign aims at raising awareness of the risks of crossing borders without the necessary papers. The officials did not have hard data to assign the treatment, only their hunch. Re study design, the research team did not have any control over the treatment, so no, it’s not a stepped wedge design (although I wish it was). Re recall data, you are right; it is not strictly pre-intervention data but is a proxy.